# Array of fetched items doesn`t show after data is fetched

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, promise, fetch-api

I have this code:

```
const fetchPokemonData = async () => {
const data = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151', options)
let pokemons = []
await data.json().then(pokemon => pokemons.push(pokemon.results))
return pokemons}

const getPokemonsUrl = async () => {
const pokemonsUrls = []
const pokemonData = await fetchPokemonData()
pokemonData[0].map(pokemons => pokemonsUrls.push(pokemons.url))

return pokemonsUrls}

const createPokemonObject = async () => {
const urls = await getPokemonsUrl()
const arrayOfPokemons = []
urls.map(async url =>{
    const data = await fetch(url)
    const pokemon = await data.json()

    const { name, id, sprites: {other: {dream_world: {front_default}}}, types, weight, stats } = pokemon

    arrayOfPokemons.push(
        {
            name: name,
            id: id, 
            image: front_default, types: types,
            weight: weight,
            stats: stats
        }
    )
})
console.log(arrayOfPokemons) //works
arrayOfPokemons.map(pokemon => console.log(pokemon)) // works only after setTimeout() delay }
```

The problem is when I try to log each pokemon outside urls.map() array function, there is no each individual Pokemon, because the data isn`t fetched yet (I tested that put by putting arrayOfPokemons inside setTimeout() function and after some delay time, each Pokemon was shown). Can someone please rewrite or explain the way to rewrite this code do that I get all individual pokemons outside of urls.map() function, because that is the best way for me to learn.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- `push` returns the length of the array, not data. Instead of using `push`, really *map* the data with a `.map` and capture the returned array.
- `.map(async` will execute the async callbacks immediately and continue. There is no waiting for those callbacks to terminate their asynchronous code. Either use a normal `for` loop or use `await Promise.all`

Here is a correction of your code:

```js
const fetchPokemonData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151');
    const pokemon = await data.json();
    return pokemon.results;
}

const getPokemonsUrl = async () => {
    const pokemons = await fetchPokemonData();
    return pokemons.map(pokemon => pokemon.url);
}

const createPokemonObject = async () => {
    console.log("wait for it...");
    const urls = await getPokemonsUrl();
    const arrayOfPokemons = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
        const data = await fetch(url);
        const pokemon = await data.json();

        const { name, id, sprites: {other: {dream_world: {front_default}}}, types, weight, stats } = pokemon;

        return {
            name: name,
            id: id, 
            image: front_default, types: types,
            weight: weight,
            stats: stats
        };
    }));
    console.log(arrayOfPokemons);
}

createPokemonObject();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @trincot! The explanation was very helpful, as I researched further this problem when you correct functions! You`re MVP!